# jQuery animation and bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change CSS values when the slide appears. I've checked out a similar question and tried that method but I haven't had any luck with it so far.

I know that I can accomplish this with CSS but I would prefer to use jQuery as I have a lot of animation to do.

```js
$('.slide-header').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(this).find('.active .slide-header').css('display', 'block');
    );
});
```

```css
.slide-header {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item active" id="item-one">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="slide-header">Slide Header</h1>
            <p class="slide-description">Slide Description</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xbak4maj/1/

Event should attach to the carousel and not to slide:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  ...
  <div class="item active" id="item-1">
  ...
  <div class="item active" id="item-2">
  ...
</div>
```

**JQ:**

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    $(this).find('.active .slide-header').css('display', 'block');
})
```

Comment: Oh I understand now, it makes much more sense. Thank you for your answer.